# Hyphen between All and India in for example, All-india Medical Institute

Tags: hyphenation

Do we need a hyphen between *All* and *India* in, for example, *All-India Medical Institute?*

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all-England+team%2Call+England+team%2C&year_start=1975&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20-%20England%20team%3B%2Cc0) for ***all-England team***, the hyphen is standard for such contexts. Including explicitly adjectival [***all-American boy.***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all-American+boy%2Call+American+boy&year_start=1975&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20-%20American%20boy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20American%20boy%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: "All-India" is a compound word, so yes it should certainly have a hyphen.  Think of the alternative:  "All India Medical Institute".  This looks like the first half of a sentence regarding all of the Medical Insitutes in India.

Answer (score 5):

The rule in English is that if a compound is used as an attributive adjective it needs a hyphen. Thus, "All-India Medical Institute" is correct.